# Rank of non-singular matrix post multiplied by a singular matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

$Y$ is a matrix that is full rank with dimensions $n\times j$. Suppose also, $A$ is a $j\times j$ matrix not of full rank. Prove that $YA$ not full rank.

I figured that since the outcome is an $n\times j$ matrix. The rank would probably be $j$ since it is probably the rank of $Y$?

Comment: I had an error in the question. It should be "why is YA not full rank?".

Comment: That's false. Under those hypothesis (i.e. that $\operatorname{rk}A<j$ and $\operatorname{rk}Y=\min\{n,j\}$), $YA$ will be full rank if and only if $n<j$ and $\Bbb F^j=\ker Y\oplus\operatorname{col}A$.